# my drop down menu of nav bar disappear behind the header

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I should have a drop down menu just like this:

[image]

but mine looks like this:

[image]

I don't know if is it useful to know that my navbar is a ha-header navbar of tympanus:
http://tympanus.net/Development/HeaderEffects/

```css
.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9999999;
}
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}
.dropdown-content a {
  display: block;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover,
.dropdown-content a:focus {
  background-image: none;
}
.dropdown-content a:last-child a:hover,
.dropdown-content a:focus {
  background-image: none;
}
.dropdown-content a:first-child a:hover,
.dropdown-content a:focus {
  background-image: none;
}
.dropdown-content a {
  width: 210px;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
.parallax-header {
  /* The image used / background-image: url("header.jpg"); / Create the parallax scrolling effect */
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <a href="#">legal solutions</a>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

and here is my site if the ispact element helps you:)
www.valaw.gigfa.com

Comment: can you please add the first image?

Comment: sorry i didn't notice , done

Comment: Can you show the CSS properties of the image that overlaps the dropdown menu?

Comment: .parallax-header {
  /* The image used */
  background-image: url("header.jpg");
  /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height:100vh;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
 }

Comment: Update the question instead of adding unformatted comments

Comment: Dear @BehnooshMzd accepting and upvoting answers will be an inspiration to whom it answered

Comment: yes i agree with you, i wasn't online till now, let me check the answers:)thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have find out your issue please remove the `overflow:hidden` in your css

```
.ha-header-perspective > div {
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
    height: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden; /* remove this overflow hidden */
    position: relative;
    text-align: justify;
    transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
    width: 100%;
 }
```

Comment: this is the site maybe the ispact helps you: www.valaw.gigfa.com "just i commen the html code of dropdown"

Comment: don't need to comment the dropdown, uncomment it let us check

Comment: can you check this now ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a `overflow: hidden` property setting on `.ha-header-front`

Insert this in the css file:

```
.ha-header-front {
   overflow: visible !important;
}
```